# Is this an example of anti-pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Me and one of my colleague were trying to solve the following problem:

Lets take an example of class A
One of my colleagues was facing problem of extracting one particular property from A.
Fetching one property from One particular class (in this case A) is easy. but lets 
assume that you have multiple classes (A1, A2...) and you want to fetch one 
particular property from the collection of these classes with more and more reusability of code.

for example

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    .
    .
    .
}
List<String> listOfNames = createNameList(listOfAInstances);
```

createNameList() method would be like following:

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(A a : listOfAInstances) {
    tempList.add(a.getName());
}
return tempList;
```

now if there are multiple classes I have to do this for each class and different properties.

I suggested two approaches:

1. Reflection based approach.
2. Create an interface called "PropertyExtractable" and put a method in it called "extractProperty" in it.

As shown below:

```
interface PropertyExtractable {
    Object extractProperty();
}

public class A implements PropertyExtractable {
    private String name;
    .
    .
    .
    public Object extractProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

For this I can write some utility method which then can be used everywhere i.e.

```
    public Object getPropertiesOfPropertyExtractable(PropertyExtractable prExtractable) {
        return prExtractable.extractProperty();
    }
```

This was the background, one other colleague of mine had different opinion about 2nd approach, he told me it seems like anti-pattern. He tried to explain to me but I didn't get it entirely so and hence I am asking here.

I am trying to compare this example with the Comparator interface in Java. Like java allows us to use Comparator on any of the custom object class and allows us to define the logic for comparison then why can't I define the logic for extraction

Further more interfaces can be used in this way, then why shouldn't we use it

I want to know is this approach an anti-pattern?  why?

Comment: Hmm, my first thought was that it is not type-safe. Then, if you can have a list of different classes, then you already need to have a common interface of those. Why not include a `String getName()` there?

Comment: It helps a lot if your example code and "for example" text match up with their class names.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use more specific return types in overridden methods: `public String extractProperty()` in `A`. Then, if you've got a reference to an `A`, you can write `String name = myA.extractProperty();`, with no need to cast.

Comment: corrected, sorry for trouble

Comment: @AndyTurner wouldn't that only function correctly if `myA` is declared as `A` then? If he has a Collection of `PropertyExtractable` instead of `A`, because it could also contain `B` ...

Comment: @Fildor "Then, if you've got a reference to an A". Yes.

Comment: I don't know if it is a true anti-pattern (that is pretty opinionated), but it seems like a lot of effort and the introduction if hard to read abstract code just to not have to repeat one type of method. You still have to endlessly repeat plenty of others such as equals(), hashCode(), toString(), constructors, etc. etc. That's just the nature of the language and a reason why people switch over to "leaner" languages.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, that's the point. I read the question that it is the actual issue, that he doesn't have necessarily a reference to `A`. Or better a reference of type `A`. It could still *be* an `A`.

Comment: _"you want to fetch one particular property from the collection of these classes"_ what do you mean exactly by this? Filter out the duds and return a collection of the properties? Or use a reducing operation to make the extracted properties into 1 values?

Comment: It means that extract only "name" property from the collection of Person class.

Comment: Yes I get _that_ part, but would that return only 1 `String` for all of them, or a `List<String>` for instance?

Comment: @JornVernee First snippet: `List<String> listOfNames = createNameList(listOfAInstances);` So I was assuming a list of the property values.

Comment: Oh, I'm blind. Sorry. I had a solution to a very similar problem, but the properties would be added together in that.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the use case would look like though. Does each subclass have exactly 1 property? Do you you call for instance `List<SomeA1Property> list = createA1PropertyList(listOfAInstances);`?

Comment: to be frank this is just a problem which one of my colleague faced in his development work, basically in reality there were number of properties in one class not only 1, I just try to represent the whole situation here by providing a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can place extracting code in separate method and reuse it:

```
class A {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class B {
    private String surname;

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}

public class SomeClass {

    private <T> List<String> extractFields(List<T> list, Function<T, String> extractorFunction) {
        return list.stream().map(extractorFunction).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void someMethod() {

        List<A> listOfInstancesA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<B> listOfInstancesB = new ArrayList<>();

        // fill lists

        List<String> fieldsA = extractFields(listOfInstancesA, A::getName);
        List<String> fieldsB = extractFields(listOfInstancesB, B::getSurname);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I posted this question is not to find the solution of the problem, but to find the right approach to do it. As I mentioned I already have two approach defined for this I can choose either of it, it will work I am sure of it.

Comment: My suggestion is neither reflection nor creating of interfaces, that's why I suggested you this. It will not touch initial classes A and B.

Comment: thanks for this new approach :) but I see it as more general problem, I have used Java here because I know it a bit, but lets assume if the same thing is in Swift/JavaScript or any other language.

Comment: As for javascript, it is dynamic language and it much easier to implement it. For example my Java sample can be ranslated to Javascript like this: http://pastebin.com/TjVj7aCi. I sure there is better sample because I'm not Javascript expert.

Comment: @BilboBaggins You don't build a wall the same way when using concrete, bricks or wood. What I am saying: I don't think this can be generalized to a lang-agnostic approach. Because then it would be a pattern, which in turn will be implemented differently in different languages. Sometimes differently in the same language ...

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is working with a legacy system which you don't want to change.

Since if you weren't you'd introduce an interface for the common properties (like your example for the Comparator interface). You introduced an interface without a meaning which may be an anti-pattern since you actually need a functional interface: PropertyExtractable vs. NamedObject=> has a method: String getName()).

*If* you want to implement Reflection, then your interface may be correct but I don't see it (e.g. in your case you already *have* Reflection built in into Java).

Usually you use the Adapter pattern to get a property/method from an object which doesn't implement the requested interface.

Comment: I didn't understand this part "You introduced an interface without a meaning" what is the exact "meaning" that I should look for in such cases?

Comment: You moved to a level of abstraction, where the use of such an interface is universal: e.g. this is what I meant by the use case, if you're trying to create a method for reflection, then it is ok, since Reflection works on the actual structure of the code (objects, classes, properties, etc.). But you're use case is concrete (named objects) stemming from a concrete domain. You have to look for the common properties of the domain and whether you can derive an interface from it (my example was NamedObject Interface).

Comment: My properties are not common (can't move them to a common interface), but I want a common behavior across all classes which when called can return a particular property (which is already decided) should return, the basis of entire question is because one of my colleague has 8 to 10 classes in Swift out of which he wants to extract a particular property to display on screen (may be in a drop down). So as I mentioned there could be two approach, reflection/ use of interface to force every implementation to use this behavior of getting property.

Comment: You are describing exactly the requirements for a reflection interface. Now you can decide how to go about it, i.e. use a language that has it already (Swift has Mirror) or try to do it yourself. If you do it yourself, you can try it with an interface or with a precompile step (like c++/qt and moc) or some other implementation, e.g. each object has a map of available properties which can be queried. Each approach has its trade-offs.